# How to DHCP request a second, different, IP for the same physical interface?

Tags: dhcp, gentoo, iproute2, dhclient

(Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/308811/how-to-request-dhcp-using-dhclient-on-a-virtual-interface-i-e-eth01), but with *two* different DHCP-assigned IPs)

Is there any way to let `dhclient` or `dhcpcd` request two different IPs for one physical interface, e.g. via virtual interfaces `eth0` and `eth0:1`? Maybe by letting `eth0:1` have a different MAC? Or by creating a virtual `eth1` bridged to `eth0`? Or can I use `ip addr add` directly somehow?

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/337331/request-multiple-ip-addresses-via-dhcp-on-a-single-physical-interface-openbsd

Answer (score 0):

If eth0:1 has a different MAC, dhcpd should provide a second address automatically, unless it is on a different VLAN.

Comment: Do I actually have to use a virtual interface or can `ip` associate a second IP with a different MAC automatically?

Comment: You could have the same MAC address on a second interface, but you would probably have to add the ip manually or via the system configuration files. If you're asking if a single interface can have multiple MAC addresses, no, that's why there are interfaces like eth0:1, eth0:2, etc..

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Turns out my kernel doesn't currently support virtual interfaces (`ifconfig eth0:1 up` yields `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address`, and `ip link add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan` a `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`) so I have to fix _that_ first...

Comment: You did create the corresponding files for eth0:1 `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1` and made sure the Device name at the top is `eth0:1` ? This of course the RH model, Debian systems use a different one..

Comment: No, but since currently I just want to temporarily test whether this works at, shouldn't `ifconfig eth0:1 up` suffice?

Comment: Not unless you specify the values it needs.. try `ifconfig eth0:1 <ip> netmask <mask>` , up calls the ifcfg-eth0:1 script.

Comment: Hm, if I assign a static IP `eth0:1` is up, but static is what I'd like to avoid... And if I add `hw ether SOMEMAC` the MAC gets also assigned to `eth0`

Comment: It would be a lot easier to make a new file for the eth0:0 interface, copy the eth0 file, and name it eth0:0, change the device name at the top, then alter any other options, like the MAC, the IP (if it's static, etc)..

Answer (score 0):

No. The virtual interface is still the same underlying *physical* interface, and the MAC address is part of the physical interface, not the virtual interface.

You need to make one of the addresses static.

Comment: I am very certain that this is either wrong or we misunderstand one another - a virtual machine can easily obtain its own IP via (a bridge and) DHCP

Comment: So, if I type `ifconfig eth0:2 down` `ifconfig eth0:2 ifconfig hw ether 11:22:33:44:55:66` then `ifconfig eth0:2 up` I wouldn't actually be changing the address?

Comment: @NickW Unless something has changed since the last time I tried this, then that is correct. Your commands don't work for me on CentOS 6 (`ifconfig eth0:1 hw ether 11:22:33:44:55:66` == `SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy`). I am happy to be corrected if this has been changed in recent kernels.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler My understanding is that we're talking about Virtual NIC's (ie, eth0:1), not Virtual Machines (eg, KVM, Xen etc)

Comment: Hm, now when I re-read my question I realize I have indeed unnecessarily narrowed it, I broadened it a bit now - from what I read so far (but could not test due to a lack of supporting Kernel) at the very least iproute2's `macvlan` [should](http://serverfault.com/a/224295/45248) allow assigning multiple MACs to one physical interface

Comment: @fukawi2 In your ifcfg-ethX files, if you add MACADDR= you can assign it a different address. I can't see in the ifconfig man pages if it is possible to do it via the command line, you do need to make sure the interface is down.